# How to put php tag in .js file?

Tags: javascript, php, function, codeigniter, file

I have code javascript with tag php in one file, in footer.html exactly.
The php tag is work for calling method in a controller using url.
when I separate the JS from footer.php in files .js the tag php is not working.

```
<?php echo site_url('index.php/master_ekspor/ajax_edit/')?>/
```

How to add/use/put php function on .JS file?

This is my .js function ?

```
function edit_ekspor(id)
        {
              save_method = 'update_ekspor';
              $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

              //Ajax Load data from ajax
              $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo site_url('index.php/master_ekspor/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    $('[name="id_ekspor"]').val(data.id_ekspor);
                    $('[name="nm_industri"]').val(data.nm_industri);
                    $('[name="e_berat"]').val(data.e_berat);
                    $('[name="e_nilai"]').val(data.e_nilai);
                    $('[name="tahun"]').val(data.tahun);


                    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
                    $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data Ekspor'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alertify.error("Gagal Mendapatkan Data");
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: that would work , if the file was actually be parsed as php, on most installs by default it would not. depending on server, you will have to tell it to parse *.js files, or just this one

Answer (score 2):

You can not write PHP code in the javascript file. You should declare url a variable in header section as:

```
<script>
var url = "<?php echo site_url('index.php/master_ekspor/ajax_edit/')?>";
</script>
```

Then use that variable in .js file as below.

```
function edit_ekspor(id)
        {
              save_method = 'update_ekspor';
              $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals

              //Ajax Load data from ajax
              $.ajax({
                url : url +"/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    $('[name="id_ekspor"]').val(data.id_ekspor);
                    $('[name="nm_industri"]').val(data.nm_industri);
                    $('[name="e_berat"]').val(data.e_berat);
                    $('[name="e_nilai"]').val(data.e_nilai);
                    $('[name="tahun"]').val(data.tahun);


                    $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
                    $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data Ekspor'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alertify.error("Gagal Mendapatkan Data");
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: actually, where can i declare it? in footer.php file or mypage.js ?

Comment: declare it just before of including mypage.js file in footer.php file

Comment: What issue is coming now?